# Binding a dependency selectlist using Knockout where the first dropdown is being populated dynamically

Tags: knockout.js, dependencies, selectlist

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.Data().filter(function(item){             
            return item.Name()==$data;
        }),optionsText: 'FieldName' "></select>
```

I have my first Selectlist being populated as above

The Data is the object which is mapped to the JSON 
The above observable has a computed function which is used for getting distinct Menu items for modeoftransport.

How should i go about the 2nd Selectlist to display the states CA, NC,AZ as list items, which are  populated once the user selects the FieldName as ABCD.

JSON returned would be something like this

FieldName: ABCD
AllowedStates : CA,NC,AZ
ModeofTRansport : Air

FieldName: EFGH
AllowedStates : OH,NC,MO,PA
ModeofTRansport : Road

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the cart editor example. It implements cascading dropdowns.

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html